# Select or bottom record from joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having an issue with data duplication in a query that I'm running in SQL Server 2005:

```
`SELECT i.datecreated, i.CompanyName, i.City, i.State, i.Phone, i.InsCoID, i.Address1, i.Zip,
case i.Reviewed when 0 then 'Pending Approval' else 'Active' end,
r.FirstName + ' ' + r.LastName AS Adjuster, r.Phone
FROM V_InsRepresentative r
RIGHT JOIN V_InsCompany i ON r.InsCoID = i.InsCoID
WHERE i.DateCreated >= '5/18/2014'
And i.DateCreated < '5/26/2014'
AND i.Status = '1'
ORDER BY     i.state, i.companyname`
```

One of the records duplicates because there are two adjusters. Is there a way to only have 1 adjuster show?

Comment: which one should it show?, and in what table is the adjuster duplicated?, and what column is the `adjuster`?

Comment: The query is to determine companies added in the date range. If there is more than 1 adjuster assigned, it is duplicating the company for each adjuster listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest fixing this in the `from` clause:

```
FROM    (SELECT r.*, row_number() over (partition by InsCoID order by INsCoId) as seqnum
         FROM V_InsRepresentative r
        ) r
        RIGHT JOIN V_InsCompany i ON r.InsCoID = i.InsCoID and r.seqnum = 1
```

This will arbitrarily choose one of the rows from the `r` table, which I believe is what you mean by duplicate inspectors.

Comment: That worked! It still keeps the null values and only selects one adjuster record. Thanks Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping your data with a Max() on adjustor so that only one adjustor will show:

```
SELECT  i.datecreated ,
        i.CompanyName ,
        i.City ,
        i.State ,
        i.Phone ,
        i.InsCoID ,
        i.Address1 ,
        i.Zip ,
        CASE i.Reviewed
          WHEN 0 THEN 'Pending Approval'
          ELSE 'Active'
        END ,
        Max(r.FirstName + ' ' + r.LastName) AS Adjuster ,
        r.Phone
FROM    V_InsRepresentative r
        RIGHT JOIN V_InsCompany i ON r.InsCoID = i.InsCoID
WHERE   i.DateCreated >= '5/18/2014'
        AND i.DateCreated < '5/26/2014'
        AND i.Status = '1'
group by 
i.datecreated ,
        i.CompanyName ,
        i.City ,
        i.State ,
        i.Phone ,
        i.InsCoID ,
        i.Address1 ,
        i.Zip ,
        CASE i.Reviewed
          WHEN 0 THEN 'Pending Approval'
          ELSE 'Active'
        END ,
        r.Phone
ORDER BY i.state ,
        i.companyname
```

Comment: Do you mean there are two adjusters with the same name? Are alll columns in the duplicated record the same?

Comment: No, the company adds a row for each adjuster, and I only want to see one record for each company.

Comment: WHile this will work, it is better for the business to determine which adjustor to choose when only showing one. Perhaps they need to see both names. Perhaps the database has a way to show who is the main adjuster. This is a qeuestions first for the business and last for the sql experts on how to tackle it. The OP needs to discuss with his business how they want to determine which one to show.

Comment: @HLGEM, the business had already decided that the adjuster name was just there for name-dropping, when our sales team contacts that client. They're not really concerned so much with that info as they are with the company's info.